# How to link 2 different elements (img and number) to 2 different urls?

Tags: image, css

How can I link image from background in css to some url (#player/deposit/) and leave amount to be linked to other url (player/wallet/)?

```
<div class="player-credit-info">
    <a href="#player/wallet/">
        <div class="player-credit-amount">
            <div id="playerBalance">10000$</div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Here is the css:

```
.player-credit-info {
padding: 0px 15px 0px 50px;
display: inline-block;
background: url(../images-vm/coin@2x.png) no-repeat;
background-size: 25px 22px;
background-position-x: 15px;
background-position-y: 2px;
float: right;
margin-top: 8px;
font-size: 18px;
```

}

I am not HTML programmer, but even it did not look complicate at first sight, I got stuck to keep both coin image and amount in the same line and to be linked to 2 different urls.  I tried to exclude image in img tag, but did not get neat solution. Thank you for the help.

Comment: the question is not clear, do you want the background show two images?or the a element link to two urls?

Comment: Sounds like you want a link within a link. That would not be valid html. I *think* you can only do this with javascript.

Comment: No, I do not want link under link. I want to separate 2 HTML elements, coin image and amount, and each of them to have point to 2 different links - no need to have coin image as background.

Comment: Don't nest the anchors and wrap the coin img & the amount with a separate one. E.g.: `<a>Coin img</a><a>Amount</a>` You can make them siblings but that's optional, can also put them inside the `divs`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I know what i cannot do or it is not recommended to do - I posted this because I am not HTML developer ( although I know a lot)  and to ask how to do it - I tried many things and could not get correct result. I am not posting this to ask others to do work for me - I put them in different anchors - that is the only solution - but how to combine with current css to keep the look the same as before - just with different links.

Comment: Solved it. Regards